# $\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)e^{\frac{-y}{2}}dydx$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

The value of the integral
$$\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)e^{\frac{-y}{2}}dydx$$
is ______

I tried to solve it using substitution but did not succeed as I didn't find any favourable substitution to make above Integral easier one,I am totally stuck how to approach this type of problem in which limits of integration are involving infinity in case of multiple integrals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This integral is a classic example where the order of integration is important.

Your integral can be easily evaluated by rewriting it as

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-y/2}}{y}\Bigg[\int_0^y dx  \Bigg]dy$$

Comment: thanks a lot,such a easy approach!